# Passing PropTypes values through props to a stateful React child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I established my PropTypes on App component for all props that are being passed to children.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        this.state = {
            anyProps : undefined',
        };
    }

    propsValues = {
        anyProp: [ 'undefined', 'neutral', 'evil', 'good' ],
    };

   (...)
```

I can receive PropTypes on child stateless components, and use its value to validate other props, like this:

```
const SFComponent = ({
    anyProp,
    propsValues,
}) => {

    SFComponent.propTypes = {
        anyProp : PropTypes.oneOf( propsValues.anyProp ).isRequired,
        propsValues : PropTypes.objectOf( PropTypes.arrayOf( PropTypes.string )),
    }; 

    (...)
```

But when I try to do the same with a child stateful component it just doesn't work. I can't use the same sintaxis and props are still not received when valitdating types.

```
class StatefulComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            anyAttribute : true,
            anotherAttribute : null,
        };
    }

    static propTypes = {
        anyProp : PropTypes.oneOf( this.props.propsValues.anyProp ).isRequired,
        propsValues : PropTypes.objectOf( PropTypes.arrayOf( PropTypes.string )),

    (...)
```

The above snippet throws an error stating **this** is undefined. I've also tried other possibilities but none works.

So, any ideas on how can I achieve the same result that I achieve in stateless components, being able to use `props.propsValues` as a base validator for all my props on child stateful components?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`this.props` don't exist at the moment when `propTypes` is used because `propTypes` is static.

`SFComponent` is a hack that won't work as intended because `SFComponent.propTypes` affects only component next render. This should be done with HOC:

```
const withAnyProp = Comp => ({ anyProp, ...props }) =>
  const Wrapper = (...props) => <Comp {...props} />;
  Wrapper.propTypes = {
    anyProp : PropTypes.oneOf(anyProp).isRequired,
  };
  return <Wrapper {...props} />;
};
const SFComponentWithAnyProp = withAnyProp(SFComponent);
```

Orop types are just built-in replacement for *static* type checks. TypeScript or Flow types should preferably be used instead.

In case it's needed to use *dynamic* type checks, props can be asserted directly, in functional component body or class component hook methods.

Comment: I've searched for something like this for a few hours but I don't understand this syntax quite well. Can you edit so it's a working example? (or add a description of what you're trying to do). For example, I don't know if you're passing a function as argument for the withAnyProp functional component in the first line, and what is SFComponentWithAnyProp at the end. I've only seen HOCs that are exported at the end, and then used in another components.